# Issues with ActionBarSherlock - Install fails on Android 2.3.7

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem using ActionBarSherlock in one of my projects. My App installs fine when pushing it to my Nexus 4, but when I try to install it to my HTC Desire (CM7 with Android 2.3.7 - API Level 10) I get the following error.

```
[2013-02-03 18:47:44 - MyApp] Project dependency found, installing: Actionbar
[2013-02-03 18:47:44 - Actionbar] Uploading Actionbar.apk onto device 'HT042PL03910'
[2013-02-03 18:47:44 - Actionbar] Installing Actionbar.apk...
[2013-02-03 18:47:47 - Actionbar] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
[2013-02-03 18:47:47 - Actionbar] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-02-03 18:47:47 - MyApp] Launch canceled!
```

I am using Sherlock 4.2.0 as a libraryproject and added the R11 of android-support-v4. Sherlock itself is configured like this:

```
Manifest:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>


Project-Properties:

android.library=true
# Project target.
target=android-14
```

My application uses the following settings:

```
Manifest:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


Project-Properties:

target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:16
android.library.reference.1=../ActionbarSherlock
```

I went through the whole logcat output but couldn't find anything helpful. Has anybody else experienced this and can help me?

========= EDIT ===============

Manifest of my App (mindSdk changed to 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        (...Activities and Services here ...)

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Full Logcat from new Emulator AVD with Google APIs Level 10:

```
02-03 21:09:59.647: I/PackageManager(77): Removing non-system package:de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp
02-03 21:09:59.647: I/ActivityManager(77): Force stopping package de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp uid=10038
02-03 21:09:59.877: D/dalvikvm(77): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1369K, 49% free 5484K/10631K, external 3226K/4029K, paused 4ms+12ms
02-03 21:09:59.977: D/PackageManager(77): Scanning package de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp
02-03 21:09:59.977: I/PackageManager(77): Package de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp codePath changed from /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-1.apk to /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
02-03 21:09:59.977: I/PackageManager(77): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk
02-03 21:10:00.047: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk' ---
02-03 21:10:04.096: D/dalvikvm(598): DexOpt: load 250ms, verify+opt 957ms
02-03 21:10:04.306: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk' (success) ---
02-03 21:10:04.306: W/PackageManager(77): Code path for pkg : de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp changing from /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-1.apk to /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk
02-03 21:10:04.306: W/PackageManager(77): Resource path for pkg : de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp changing from /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-1.apk to /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk
02-03 21:10:04.306: D/PackageManager(77):   Services: de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.GCMIntentService de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.services.LocationService de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.services.SyncService de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.services.AppService de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.services.AuthService
02-03 21:10:04.306: D/PackageManager(77):   Receivers: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver
02-03 21:10:04.306: D/PackageManager(77):   Activities: de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.LoginActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.MessageEditor de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.StartActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.ContactsActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.KlingelSettings de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.NewStartActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.MessagesActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.MessageDetails de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.RegisterActivity de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.ui.FriendRequestActivity
02-03 21:10:04.306: D/PackageManager(77):   Permissions: de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
02-03 21:10:04.326: I/ActivityManager(77): Force stopping package de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp uid=10038
02-03 21:10:04.436: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk@classes.dex
02-03 21:10:04.436: D/PackageManager(77): New package installed in /data/app/de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-2.apk
02-03 21:10:04.446: W/PackageManager(77): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
02-03 21:10:04.446: W/PackageManager(77): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
02-03 21:10:04.457: W/PackageManager(77): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
02-03 21:10:04.457: W/PackageManager(77): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
02-03 21:10:04.466: W/PackageManager(77): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.android.email
02-03 21:10:04.476: W/PackageManager(77): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
02-03 21:10:04.476: W/PackageManager(77): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
02-03 21:10:04.606: I/ActivityManager(77): Force stopping package de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp uid=10038
02-03 21:10:04.706: D/dalvikvm(260): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 49% free 3020K/5831K, external 4756K/5631K, paused 67ms
02-03 21:10:04.746: D/dalvikvm(226): GC_EXPLICIT freed 94K, 51% free 2964K/5959K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 75ms
02-03 21:10:04.806: W/RecognitionManagerService(77): no available voice recognition services found
02-03 21:10:04.856: D/GTalkService(287): handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
02-03 21:10:04.856: D/GTalkService(287): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
02-03 21:10:04.856: D/GTalkService(287): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
02-03 21:10:05.136: I/Launcher(260): setLoadOnResume
02-03 21:10:05.226: D/dalvikvm(77): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1202K, 54% free 4962K/10631K, external 3226K/4029K, paused 75ms
02-03 21:10:05.256: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@de.hsrm.medieninf.mobcomp.klingelapp-1.apk@classes.dex
02-03 21:10:05.296: D/AndroidRuntime(589): Shutting down VM
02-03 21:10:05.306: D/dalvikvm(589): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 72% free 295K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 0ms+1ms
02-03 21:10:05.306: D/jdwp(589): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-03 21:10:05.306: D/dalvikvm(589): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-03 21:10:05.326: I/dalvikvm(589): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
02-03 21:10:05.326: I/AndroidRuntime(589): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
02-03 21:10:06.686: D/AndroidRuntime(604): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-03 21:10:06.686: D/AndroidRuntime(604): CheckJNI is ON
02-03 21:10:07.106: D/AndroidRuntime(604): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-03 21:10:07.196: D/dalvikvm(442): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 51% free 2727K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 43ms
02-03 21:10:07.206: W/ActivityManager(77): No content provider found for: 
02-03 21:10:07.306: W/ActivityManager(77): No content provider found for: 
02-03 21:10:07.316: D/PackageParser(77): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-63285559.tmp
02-03 21:10:07.326: W/PackageParser(77): /data/app/vmdl-63285559.tmp (at Binary XML file line #8): Requires newer sdk version #16 (current version is #10)
```

Comment: Can you share logcat output?

Comment: I updated my post, still no luck in figuring out what I am doing wrong. I created another project that uses the same sherlock-project as a library and has the same buildtarget, min- and maxsdk as my project. The new project installs without problems.

Comment: last line is...Requires newer sdk version #16 (current version is #10). Does your project run on 2.3.7 without ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: Yes it did. Before I integrated sherlock, I only tested it on emulators and devices that were running on api-level 10. Everything worked fine until today.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of searching for where I went wrong, I checked out a working revision without sherlock. I then added sherlock as a library and made the same changes to my activites I did yesterday. But now, install works fine.